# Disabling Request Logs Discrepancy in Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel, logging, monolog

For each request that happens on my Laravel API, this line is logged in the Laravel Docker container of my Sail dev environment:

```
2023-11-18 08:51:13 ................................................... ~ 0s
```

In production, I also see a log for every request in my Laravel container, but with a slightly other format:

```
2023-11-17T12:34:58.790851089Z 172.18.0.12 -  17/Nov/2023:12:34:58 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
```

I'm trying to disable these logs, but I'm unsure where to make the necessary changes. Any guidance on where to look or how to disable these logs would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/1024108/how-to-disable-php-fpm-request-logging